# Register Navigation Service to Frame Element and NOT the page - WinRt Prism 2.0

Tags: mvvm, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, prism

Can anyone help.

We are working on an app which has a consistent header and footer and therefore ideally we'll use one viewmodel for the "home page" but we want the header and footer to remain.

Before we switched to starting using Prism, this was easy enough to navigate as we could control that in the Pages event and set the page.contentFrame.Navigate method to go where we wanted.

Now we're using the MVVM structure (which is superb and wish I'd done it ages ago) the NavigationService class only navigates the entire page (the VisualStateAware page).

How can I set this up so that when calling the Navigate method on the interface in the viewmodel that only the main content frame is ever navigated? or is there a better approach to this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question title seems to, pre-empt the details of the question slightly as a solution. But to share a common view model and visual parts across all pages, within a frame, using the navigation service to navigate between pages here is an overview..

1. Create a shared ViewModel, say "HeaderViewModel" of type say IHeaderViewModel to be shared between the different pages' view models. Inject this into the constructor of each page's ViewModel.
2. Then expose this as a property of each page's ViewModel. This property could also be called HeaderViewModel too. You can then reference the properties of this common HeaderViewModel in the bindings in the View, using binding '.' notation.
3. If you are using Unity with Prism, you can create this shared instance HeaderViewModel in the OnInitialize override of the App.
4. Create a shared part for each Page/View as a UserControl, which can be positioned on each page in the same place. This enables you to bind to the same properties on your HeaderViewModel.

Comment: Brilliant thank you. My brain was having none of that as a possible solution earlier.