# Win universal app using Prism NavigationService with Frame control

Tags: c#, xaml, navigation, prism, win-universal-app

How to us the Prism NavigationService combined with the Frame control? 
I have a main page which includes a Frame. First, I have to navigate to the main page, after that I want to change the NavigationSerices so that it uses the Frame instead of the whole page.

So I need something like regions from Prism 5.0 in the Windows-Store-App-Prism framework.

A similar problem was already solved: [Register Navigation Service to Frame Element and NOT the page - WinRt Prism 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061222/register-navigation-service-to-frame-element-and-not-the-page-winrt-prism-2-0) 
but I don't like this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: In the App.xaml.cs which inherits from MvvmAppBase add:

```
public static App Instance { get { return _instance; } }

private Type Resolve(string name)
{
    return Type.GetType(string.Format("{0}.Views.{1}Page", this.GetType().Namespace, name));
}

public void CreateNewNavigationFrame(Frame frame)
{
    this.NavigationService = new FrameNavigationService(new FrameFacadeAdapter(frame), Resolve, this.SessionStateService);
}
```

In the constructor of the main page (the page where the Frame is):

```
    public AppShellPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        App.Instance.CreateNewNavigationFrame(this.frame);
    }
```

Comment: Currently this is a problem in PRISM. This solution will cause some problems in the framework, all other solution I tried have similar issues. So we have to wait for Regions in PRISM for Win10.

Comment: Regions for Prism UWP is on the agenda, but probably won't make it into the first RTM release.