# UWP Prism NavigationService configuration

Tags: windows-phone, prism, uwp

I've started a UWP project with Prism Library. To navigate between pages I'm using Prism NavigationService. Well everything is ok while I have situation as in bellow image:
[image: application start flow]

Well after login I need to load a window with a split view and later to use NavigationService to change only content of the "red square".

[image: later application flow]

My third page xaml looks like:

```
 <SplitView x:Name="rootSplitView" Style="{StaticResource MenuSplitViewStyle}" Grid.Row="1">
            <Frame x:Name="contentFrame"/>

            <SplitView.Pane>
                <views:MenuViewPage/>
            </SplitView.Pane>
        </SplitView>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="togglePaneButton"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsPaneOpen,
                                          ElementName=rootSplitView,
                                          Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Style="{StaticResource SplitViewTogglePaneButtonStyle}"
                      TabIndex="1" />
```

My app bootstrap is:

```
public sealed partial class App : PrismUnityApplication
{
    protected override Task OnLaunchApplicationAsync(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args) 
        {

            if (args != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Arguments))
            {
                // The app was launched from a Secondary Tile
                // Navigate to the item's page
                //NavigationService.Navigate("ItemDetail", args.Arguments);
            }
            else
            {
                // Navigate to the initial page
                NavigationService.Navigate(PageTokens.IntroPage, null);
            }

            Window.Current.Activate();
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
...
}
```

My question is how I can create a region in red square and configure navigation service to use the region to navigate between pages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Win universal app using Prism NavigationService with Frame control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766579/win-universal-app-using-prism-navigationservice-with-frame-control)

Comment: I was looking at it a while ago, and it looks like you either have to repeat the layout on all your views, or you can use Frame (if I remember correctly) and then navigate inside that Frame (manually, there is a method navigate to), but you can't use Prism for that navigation, because it will replace the entire usercontrol anytime you navgigate.

Comment: Do you found an answer? I am looking for the same.

Comment: Well I do not work on that project anymore and I do not have access to source code, but solution overview is next: create a shell, with main region. Welcome screen, register screen, login screen and main application screen will be user controls ( you may move them in a different module). To navigate between them use Navigation service. BUT main app screen should be user control (menu showed) and in red you will use another region and change views in it based on RegionContext that is changed by left menu.